# What is the fastest way to read in a large data file of text columns?

Tags: python, c, io, dataset

I have a data file of almost 9 million lines (soon to be more than 500 million lines) and I'm looking for the fastest way to read it in. The five aligned columns are padded and separated by spaces, so I know where on each line to look for the two fields that I want.
My Python routine takes 45 secs:

```
import sys,time

start = time.time()
filename = 'test.txt'    # space-delimited, aligned columns
trans=[]
numax=0
for line in open(linefile,'r'):
    nu=float(line[-23:-11]); S=float(line[-10:-1])
    if nu>numax: numax=nu
    trans.append((nu,S))
end=time.time()
print len(trans),'transitions read in %.1f secs' % (end-start)
print 'numax =',numax
```

whereas the routine I've come up with in **C** is a more pleasing 4 secs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BPL 47
#define FILENAME "test.txt"
#define NTRANS 8858226

int main(void) {
  size_t num;
  unsigned long i;
  char buf[BPL];
  char* sp;
  double *nu, *S;
  double numax;
  FILE *fp;
  time_t start,end;

  nu = (double *)malloc(NTRANS * sizeof(double));
  S = (double *)malloc(NTRANS * sizeof(double));

  start = time(NULL);
  if ((fp=fopen(FILENAME,"rb"))!=NULL) {
    i=0;
    numax=0.;
    do {
      if (i==NTRANS) {break;}
      num = fread(buf, 1, BPL, fp);
      buf[BPL-1]='\0';
      sp = &buf[BPL-10]; S[i] = atof(sp);
      buf[BPL-11]='\0';
      sp = &buf[BPL-23]; nu[i] = atof(sp);
      if (nu[i]>numax) {numax=nu[i];}
      ++i;
    } while (num == BPL);
    fclose(fp);
    end = time(NULL);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d lines read; numax = %12.6f\n", (int)i, numax);
    fprintf(stdout, "that took %.1f secs\n", difftime(end,start));
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", FILENAME);
    free(nu); free(S);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  free(nu); free(S);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```

Solutions in Fortran, C++ and Java take intermediate amounts of time (27 secs, 20 secs, 8 secs).
My question is: have I made any outrageous blunders in the above (particularly the **C**-code)? And is there any way to speed up the Python routine? I quickly realised that storing my data in an array of tuples was better than instantiating a class for each entry.

Comment: Please explain the magic numbers in your C code (Where do you come up with 47 and 858226?)

Comment: You should run the profiler on your python code to see where it's slow. Also you should try to follow the pep8 style conventions for python, they make it much much easier to read.

Comment: For python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896674/python-how-to-read-huge-text-file-into-memory

Comment: sorry - BPL=47 is the number of bytes per line, including the \n EOL character; 8588226 is the total number of lines in the file - so I know how much memory I'll need to store the data in.

Comment: in the python side, i guess you could speed it perceptibly by returning an iterator instead of building an array.

Comment: In the C code, you could `fread` for more than one line at a time. It may or may not actually help on any given system: depends on buffering and on the cost of a system call.

Comment: Speaking of outrageous blunders, though, you should check the return value of `fread` before using the results, rather than before repeating the loop :-)

Comment: I would use a generator to yield (nu, S) pairs instead of initialize+append, but this probably won't give you more speed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - I've got a factor of 2 back already on the Python code by loading them into a numpy array: trans = np.zeros(NTRANS, dtype=[('nu', np.double), ('S', np.double)])

Comment: You are creating 27 million objects here : (nu,S) * 9,000,000 = 27,000,000. It is pushing the envelope for Python in terms of performance. It will be fruitful to try numpy or John Machin's suggestoin on array.

Comment: Python is very slow at input and output. Do profiling, but IME you'll likely find that this is your bottleneck. The only way around this is to use a different language (like C, as it happens).

Answer (score 3):

Some points:

1. Your C routine is cheating; it is being tipped off with the filesize, and is pre-allocating ...
2. Python: consider using [array.array('d')](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array) ... one each for S and nu. Then try pre-allocation.
3. Python: write your routine as a function and call it -- accessing function-local variables is rather faster than accessing module-global variables.

Comment: Thanks - I reckon your point 2. is why reading into pre-allocated numpy arrays got me down to 20 secs. Calling it as a function and we're down to 17.3 secs. Can anyone give any pointers on how to implement the iterator method?

Answer (score 2):

In the C implementation, you could try swapping the `fopen()`/`fread()`/`fclose()` library functions for the lower-level system calls `open()`/`read()`/`close()`. A speedup may come from the fact that `fread()` does a lot of buffering, whereas `read()` does not.

Additionally, calling `read()` less often with bigger chunks will reduce the number of system calls and therefore you'll have less switching between userspace and kernelspace. What the kernel does when you issue a `read()` system call (doesn't matter if it was invoked from the `fread()` library function) is read the data from the disk and then copy it to the userspace. The copying part becomes expensive if you issue the system call very often in your code. By reading in larger chunks you'll end up with less context switches and less copying.

Keep in mind though that `read()` isn't guaranteed to return a block of the exact number of bytes you wanted. This is why in a reliable and proper implementation you always have to check the return value of the `read()`.

Comment: I don't understand. First you suggest not to use buffering by changing from fread()/... functions to read()/... functions. Then you suggest to use buffering by reading larger chunks of data. IMHO you suggest to avoid automatic buffering, and to actually use manual buffering with all the possible bug in a faulty implementation.

Comment: A proper implementation will always check the number of bytes actually read by `read()`. The point was that calling `read(2)` with a 47-byte memory block is far less efficient than doing it with a 1024-byte block for example.

Comment: Sure, but that's exactly why you use `fread()` instead - it'll call `read()` with a larger value and do the buffering for you.

Answer (score 2):

An approach that could probably be applied to the C, C++ and python version would be to use memory map the file. The most signficant benefit is that it can reduce the amount of double-handling of data as it is copied from one buffer to another. In many cases there are also benefits due to the reduction in the number of system calls for I/O.

Comment: +1; memory mappping can be done natively in Java and in Fortran via C bindings as well...

Answer (score 0):

You have the `1` and the `BPL` arguments the wrong way around in `fread()` (the way you have it, it could read a partial line, which you don't test for).  You should also be testing the return value of `fread()` *before* you try and use the returned data.

You can might be able to speed the C version up a bit by reading more than a line at a time

```
#define LINES_PER_READ 1000
char buf[LINES_PER_READ][BPL];

/* ... */

   while (i < NTRANS && (num = fread(buf, BPL, LINES_PER_READ, fp)) > 0) {
      int line;

      for (line = 0; i < NTRANS && line < num; line++)
      {
          buf[line][BPL-1]='\0';
          sp = &buf[line][BPL-10]; S[i] = atof(sp);
          buf[line][BPL-11]='\0';
          sp = &buf[line][BPL-23]; nu[i] = atof(sp);
          if (nu[i]>numax) {numax=nu[i];}
          ++i;
      }
    }
```

On systems supporting `posix_fadvise()`, you should also do this upfront, after opening the file:

```
posix_fadvise(fileno(fp), 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL);
```

Answer (score -2):

Another possible speed-up, given the number of times you need to do it, is to use pointers to S and nu instead of indexing into arrays, e.g.,

```
double *pS = S, *pnu = nu;
...
*pS++ = atof(sp);
*pnu = atof(sp);
...
```

Also, since you are always converting from char to double at the same locations in buf, pre-compute the addresses outside of your loop instead of computing them each time in the loop.

Comment: Please measure without doing this. It does not help readability, and has usually no effect at all on performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I get a segmentation fault, when I do this, though?
Also, if BPL is #defined, won't the compiler do this pre-computing before execution for me?

Comment: I think most modern compilers would perform these kinds of optimizations automatically. Hence Didier's Comment.

Answer (score -2):

Don't deal with C unless ***ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY***. To try to emulate the OP's needs, I had a handy 3-column `ASCII-only` `.txt` file delimited by `'='` instead of `' '`,

spanning some `148 million rows` over nearly `7.6 GiB`.

> - It's just a big file of prime numbers I use for code validation checks
> - the 3 columns being the prime's base-2 logarithm, out to a fixed width of 5 decimal places, the number itself, in straight up ASCII decimal digits, and hex of the value.

Piping the same file in 3 times yielded a synthetic input of some `444 mn rows` (not far from the `500 mn` goal mentioned by `OP`), and used`awk` to collect some basic stats of it — *(summing up 1st column as floating point value,
and column-width-grouped counts for 2nd and 3rd column)*

---

awk processed a **`444 mn rows`**, **`22.8 GiB`** synthetic flat text file, with no pre-made indices, in just **`78.26 secs`**. 9 million rows processed at the same rate would be only :

> 1.586 secs
> -

`C` is probably more hassle than it's worth when shell scripting have speeds like that.

---

```
 ( for ___ in $$ $$$$ $$$$$$; do; pv -q < "$__"; done | pvE 0.1 in0 | mawk2 ; )  

        77.05s user 7.66s system 108% cpu 1:18.26 total
gcat -b  0.00s user 0.00s system   0% cpu 1:18.26 total
```

*(hundreds of rows were pruned out for readability purposes)*

```
 log2(_)-sum :: ~ 29790561307.14320755004882812-bits

11515                 3            3            34545
11370                 3            6            68655
10369                 3            9            99762
10154                 3            12           130224

10098                 3            15           160518
...
2222                  3            4449         14761953
2000                  6            6123         18273609
1111                  165          69522        105717363

1000                  177          90270        127527948
999                   252          90522        127779696
888                   330          124305       159575346
777                   432          170421       197709843

666                   975          232761       242405211
555                   924          341022       308075370
444                   1878         553710       412565496
333                   4317         969051       571686960

222                   35214        2756478      1036817178
111                   53748        7457043      1796338806
99                    80262        8224686      1876339980
88                    95472        9469041      1991870625

77                    124485       10676904     2090514033
66                    171246       12489018     2217919404
55                    280368       14771130     2354031702
44                    827844       20983845     2649656613

33                    1502661      30431553     3001060344
22                    7765587      59774289     3729032556
11                    21562245     433469169    9124979175
9                     2761992      443583456    9223360053

8                     414552       443998008    9226676469
7                     295692       444293700    9228746313
6                     148572       444442272    9229637745
5                     23955        444466227    9229757520

4                     3183         444469410    9229770252
3                     429          444469839    9229771539
2                     54           444469893    9229771647
```

> 

```
3333                  3            855          3876831
1111                  114          38097        56141871
1000                  153          54039        72918171
999                   174          54213        73091997
888                   159          76497        94118478

777                   258          109593       121425312
666                   537          157764       155947470
555                   504          231174       200476329
444                   1212         366900       267599124

333                   4389         685701       388875105
222                   12837        1553802      619755666
111                   61842        6291783      1374531276
99                    66285        7030575      1451567319

88                    67101        7769130      1520132172
77                    149163       8927163      1614135813
66                    150294       10389507     1718099022
55                    243546       12483837     1842271380

44                    339105       15356979     1981646316
33                    692868       23890017     2301350703
22                    1083543      37376904     2664284580
11                    105021729    327544728    6535425114

9                     19497831     437237055    7612850553
8                     5280768      442517823    7655096697
7                     1395681      443913504    7664866464
6                     373872       444287376    7667109696

5                     163302       444450678    7667926206
4                     17544        444468222    7667996382
3                     1530         444469752    7668000972
2                     141          444469893    7668001254
```

> 

```
mawk2 '
BEGIN { CONVFMT = OFMT = "%.250g"
            _ ^= +( FS = "=" )
                   OFS = "=| "
} {                __ += $_
        ___[     length( $++_ )  ]++
       ____[-_ + length($(_--+_))]++
} END {

    printf("\f\f\r\t log2(_)-sum :: ~ %29.17f-bits\n\n", __)
    _____(____,
    _____(___))
}
function _____(___, _, __, ____, _______) {
    
    _ = ""
    for (_ in ___) {
        _ = length(___)
        break
    }
    if (_) {

        NF *= NF = (__ ^= NF = !_) + \
          (____  =  __)

        for (_ in ___)__ < +_ && 
                      __ = +_

        _______ = "(000|^(1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+|.....+))$"

        for (_ = ++__; --_; ) if (__ = +___[_]) { 

            $+NF += ($____ = _) * ($(____+____) = __)
            $(NF  - ____) += __

            if (_ ~ _______)
                print
         }
    }
    print "\f\r" (_ = (_ = "---=| ")_)_ (_)_ "---\f\n"
    return
}'
```