# Is there a python library for line based file reading?

Tags: python, line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: How to read huge text file into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896674/python-how-to-read-huge-text-file-into-memory)

To process a large text file(1G+) line by line , random access by any line number is desired, most importantly, without loading the whole file content into RAM. Is there a python library to do that?

It is beneficial when analyzing a large log file, read only is enough.

If there is no such standard library, I have to seek an alternative method: Find a set of function/class that can return the N-th line of sub-string from a big string-like object, so that I can mmap(yes, I mean memory-mapped file object) the file to that object then do line-based processing.

Thank you.

PS: A log file is almost sure to have variable line length.

Comment: Are all lines of the same length?

Comment: can you preprocess the file to create an index of sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that something like below might work, since the [file object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)'s method `readline()` reads one line at a time. If the lines are of arbitrary length, you need to index the positions like follows.

```
lines = [0]
with open("testmat.txt") as f:
    while f.readline():
        lines.append(f.tell())
    # now you can read an arbitrary line:
    f.seek(lines[1235])
    line = f.readline()
```

If the lines were of same length, you could just do `f.seek(linenumber*linelenght)`

Comment: This looks like the "index of sorts" to which @anijhaw referred.